# Is this a robust solution to creating output directories in a Makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I've seen a few approaches to making output directories in Make.
These include making all directories ahead of time outside of any rule, and 
making an object's destination directory as part of the object's rule.
Both of these approaches involve making directories that likely already exist.

Am I missing any gotchas or drawbacks that explain why I haven't seen the below approach?

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:

$(OBJDIR)%.o: %.c | $$(@D)/
    # Compile command

.PRECIOUS: %/
%/:
    # mkdir Command
```

Answer (score 1):

`make` is very good at dealing with files. `make` is not very good at dealing with directories.

So treating directories as implementation detail internal to the target rule makes sense, because then `make` never has to consider the directory at all:

```
MKDIR_P = mkdir -p

$(objdir)%.o: %.c
    @$(MKDIR_P) $(@D)
    $(COMPILE.c) -o $@ -c $<
```

Note that the processing and IO required for the `mkdir -p` can be neglected next to the processing and IO required for the compilation.

Comment: "`make` is not very good at dealing with directories." I've heard this before, but never with any further explanation or examples. What makes this true?

Comment: One example: `make` determines which files have changed by checking their timestamps. A directory's timestamp changes (amongst other things) when you delete a file from it or create a file in it. So the directory's timestamp changes as a side effect of something probably completely unrelated. On the other hand, if the file inside the directory changes, the directory's timestamp is unaffected. At least, that is the behaviour in Unix like operating systems. Other OSs may even do directory timestamping differently. Not a good basis to build on, is it?

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is entirely mitigated by the use of order only dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with directories is that (contrary to any other target) you don't care for their timestamp, you only need them to *exist*. Many Makefiles get directories somehow wrong, and creating them over and over again is what you observe, so `make` will never detect "*Nothing to be done for ...*".

In fact, the only thing you *need* for correct handling of directories with GNU make is an "*order only dependency*", like shown in your example. The trailing slash normally isn't needed (you seem to use it in order to have a pattern rule, I'm not sure whether this works), and you don't need `.PRECIOUS`  either. Your trick with `.SECONDEXPANSION` looks quite neat, I *guess* this will work, given the pattern rule indeed works that way (didn't try).

For an alternative, most Makefiles that handle directories correctly take a simpler approach by concatenating all needed output directories for a rule in a single variable and use this variable as a target for another rule, e.g. like in this simplified example:

```
MODULES:=src/main

OBJDIR?=obj

OBJS:=$(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(addsuffix .c,$(MODULES)))
DIRS:=$(sort $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(dir $(OBJS))))

TARGET:= myprogram

all: $(TARGET)

myprogram: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o$@ $^

$(DIRS):
    mkdir -p $(DIRS)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c Makefile | $(DIRS)
    $(CC) -c -o$@ $<

clean:
    rm -fr $(OBJDIR)

.PHONY: all clean
```

Comment: `.PRECIOUS` is needed to prevent Make from trying to delete the directories as intermediate files.

Comment: @thetic it doesn't do that. I'm not sure whether `make` **ever** tries to remove directories. It definitely never tries to remove non-empty directories.

Comment: That's not true. https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html#Chained-Rules

Comment: @thetic Revisiting this, I **assume** that *you* need `.PRECIOUS` because you use this pattern rule. AFAIK, that's not a good idea. You have to make sure all your directory names indeed end with `/` and they will be treated as intermediaries. This definitely **isn't** the case with the solution I'm suggesting here -- just try it. It's seen in many Makefiles and is (with minor variations) the only way to make it work without adding the `mkdir` in each recipe.